# Arquillian and ejb mocking - legacy application

Tags: ejb-3.0, mockito, jboss-arquillian, legacy-code, jboss-4.2.x

i'm working on legacy project (jee 5, jboss 4.2.3) and i need to write integration tests for this app. I was able to integrate arquillian remote module and run simple tests. But now i would like to mock some services in my ejb using mockito.

Example :

some ejb

```java
@Local
public interface DummyService {

     String welcomMessage();

}

@Stateless
@LocalBinding(jndiBinding = "ejb/DummyServiceBean/local")
public class DummyServiceBean implements DummyService {

     @EJB(mappedName = "ejb/DummyServiceBean2/local")
     private DummyService2 service;

     @Override
     public String welcomMessage() {
        return "world!!!!" + "   " + service.getSomething();
     }
}

@Local
public interface DummyService2 {

    String getSomething();

}

@Stateless
@LocalBinding(jndiBinding = "ejb/DummyServiceBean2/local")
public class DummyServiceBean2 implements DummyService2 {
    @Override
    public String getSomething() {
        return "sth";
    }
}
```

test class

```java
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class DummyServiceTest {

    @EJB(mappedName = "ejb/DummyServiceBean/local")
    private DummyService service;

    @Mock
    private DummyService2 service2;

    @Deployment
    public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {

        final JavaArchive javaArchive = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "test.jar")
                .addClasses(DummyService.class, DummyServiceBean.class,
                        DummyService2.class, DummyServiceBean2.class,
                        DummyServiceTest.class, InjectMocks.class)
                .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");

        return ShrinkWrap.create(EnterpriseArchive.class, "test.ear")
                .setApplicationXML(new File("application.xml"))
                .addAsLibraries( // add maven resolve artifacts to the deployment
                        DependencyResolvers.use(MavenDependencyResolver.class)
                            .loadMetadataFromPom("pom.xml")
                            .artifact("org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5")
                            .resolveAs(GenericArchive.class))
                .addAsModule(javaArchive);
    }

    @Before
    public void setupMock() {
        when(service2.getSomething()).thenReturn("qwerty");
    }

    @Test
    public void should_assert_a_behaviour() {
        System.out.println("Hello " + service.welcomMessage());
    }

}
```

I can do this by not adding DummyServiceBean2.class into archive and by creating in test directory something like :

```java
@Stateless
@LocalBinding(jndiBinding = "ejb/DummyServiceBean2/local")
public class MockDummyServiceBean2 implements DummyService2 {
    @Override
    public String getSomething() {
        return "mock sth";
    }
}
```

but this is bad practice. I got the idea to swap during runtime DummyServiceBean2 proxy reference using reflection in DummyServiceBean class for a new one with InvocationHandler which use mock inside his invoke method but it ended up on an exception

```java
IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.example.DummyService2 field com.example.DummyServiceBean.service to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy71
```

Any ideas how can i swap/replace DummyServiceBean2 proxy for new one or how can i replace invocation handler in existing one ?